# Django annotate sum with a condition on a related table

Tags: sql, django, orm, annotate

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    ...
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Order(models.Model):
    ...
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    inventory = models.ForeignKey('Inventory')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

# Not considering the orders that are not active
queryset = Inventory.objects.annotate(
    used=Sum('order__quantity')
).filter(product=product)
```

I need to get queryset of inventory that has annotated 'used' value.
'used' value is determined by quantity of all related orders but are active.

**Edit**:
To be more precise, I need to SUM quantity of only active orders.

Answer (score 2):

```
queryset = Inventory.objects.filter(product=product, 
    order__active=True).aggregate(
    Sum('order__quantity'))

sum = queryset['order__quantity__sum']
```

Comment: This filters Inventory for which orders are ONLY active.
Perhaps my question is not clear. Sorry for that.
What I'm looking for is the sum of all 'order_quantity' for orders that are active. Like nesting a filter within the sum.

Comment: That's what you need, right? `I need to get queryset of inventory that has annotated 'used' value. 'used' value is determined by quantity of all related orders but are active.`

Comment: ok updated, `sum of all 'order_quantity' for orders that are active`

Comment: I need the sum to be annotated. In raw SQL it would *probably* be something like this:

`SUM(CASE WHEN "order_invoiceline"."active" = 1 THEN "orders_invoiceline"."quantity" ELSE 0 END)`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer with raw SQL:

```
SELECT "products_inventory"."id", "products_inventory"."product_id", "products_inventory"."quantity",
SUM(CASE WHEN "orders_order"."active" = True THEN "orders_order"."quantity" ELSE 0 END)
AS "used" FROM "products_inventory"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "orders_order" ON ("products_inventory"."id" = "orders_order"."inventory_id")
WHERE "products_inventory"."product_id" = id_of_product
GROUP BY "products_inventory"."id", "products_inventory"."product_id", "products_inventory"."quantity",
ORDER BY "products_inventory"."id" ASC
```